# How is a global object constructed before a const it was declared after?

Tags: c++, variables, constructor, global

I just encountered a strange issue. In WinMain.cpp, AFTER I include a user-created header file, but BEFORE WinMain, I declare a global instance of my class Brain, like so:

```
(windows includes)
#include "BrainLib.h"
#include "Brain.h"

Brain brain;

(wndproc declaration)

WinMain() {
  (some code using Brain)
}
```

In `BrainLib.h`, I declare some constants for general program use, such as `const unsigned short SERVER_PORT = 12345;` and `const std::string SERVER_IP_STRING = "192.168.1.104";` Note that `Brain.h` also includes `BrainLib.h`

Now here it gets interesting. Brain contains a Winsock client wrapper class that will only connect to one server. Thus, the Winsock client has a constructor requiring a port/ip and no default constructor. So, it must be initialized in the Brain constructor initialization list like so:

```
Brain::Brain() : winsockClient( SERVER_PORT, SERVER_IP_STRING )
{
}
```

However, SERVER_IP_STRING is still uninitialized when the Brain constructor is called! I put a check in WinMain, and it's constructed at that point, but it seems as though the Brain constructor is called first, even though it appears second. How/why can this be?

Also, just to make this stranger: I copied the source and compiled on a different machine, and it worked as expected. Same version of MSVS 2008 running on each, though I suppose possibly with some sort of different build settings.

Comment: Have you declared `SERVER_IP_STRING` as `const string` in non-working compiler version ?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, both server variables are declared as const! Can't believe I left that out. Edited.

Comment: And the working version has literally identical source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order in which global objects are initialized is undefined.

Comment: Really? It's the silliest things that get me. Any idea how to make my code always work then?

Comment: Best was to avoid it is to not use global variables, but to wrap them in functions

Comment: I do try to avoid globals, but have generally cheated and used one, once-per-program, to pass easily between WinMain/WndProc. Guess I'll finally learn an alternative. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the order is only unspecified when they are in separate compilation units. Within a single unit, they are initialised in the order in which they are defined.